# php array in class

Tags: php

why does this not work ?

```
class Test{

  private $vars = array('ALL' => 0,
                        'ONE' => 1);

  private $var = $vars['ALL']; // this does not work

  function __construct(){
    $this->var = $vars['ALL']; // this does work
  }
}
```

code example here: http://codepad.org/QSjHMDij

why is the array not accessible in the statement

```
private $var = $vars['ALL']; // this does not work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because you can't access `$this` during the initialization of the class prior to the constructor getting called (which is implied when you tried to do it in the definition for $var.) Some languages (like C#) will let you do it, but I think PHP is one that will not.

Comment: but I don't use $this on line 8. (it's line 8 in the codepad example btw. here it would be line 6.)

Comment: You don't have to: it's implied. If you can't access `$this`, you can't access any of the member variables either. edit: Actually, it may not even be implied: I forget if it's true, but PHP may not have the same scope resolution as C++ and C#. PHP often does unusual scope resolution to avoid ambiguities, so I'd remain unsurprised.

Comment: Ok. Can I assume that the variables are only initialized when the object is initialized ?

Comment: Do you mean when the constructor is called? Yes. Moreso because PHP enforces it, though - I'd expect PHP initializes the variables in the order you write them, but that doesn't mean you can access them that way.

Comment: Just found this: "In PHP 4, only constant initializers for var variables are allowed."

Answer (score 0):

Neither "works" in the way you intend. You are not allowed to use variables when declaring instance members (hence the `unexpected T_VARIABLE` error). In the constructor you are referencing a local variable named `$vars` which does not exist, meaning you're setting `$this->var` to `NULL`.

Access the instance member by doing `$this->vars`. You can only do this in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

When declaring members (variables), you can't assign array key values of other members, it causes a parse error.

For example, you're thinking (wrong) that `$vars['ALL']` is referring to your `private $var` - which it is not - it also causes a parse error. There's no way for PHP to know that when you say:

```
private $var = $vars['ALL'];
```

that you're actually saying "I want value of $this->vars['ALL'] to be assigned to $this->var", at least not the way you wrote it. That's why you do that from within a function, where you can easily manipulate members, such as you did from the constructor.

You should declare members, their visibility and set some default values (like you did for `$var`), but you shouldn't point them to other members' values, it's simply - wrong and luckily - it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign a value to a variable which is designed to be part of an object, rather than the class. What you want is `static` variables.